# The column cannot be processed because more than 1 code page (65001 and 1252) are specified for it error

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to import data from a CSV file to an existing table. When I do, I get following error;

> SQL Server The column cannot be processed because more than 1 code page (65001 and 1252) are specified for it

My table, has index settings. I don't want to do any alternation on it.
How can I avoid it? (it is a one time data import from a CSV file)

Comment: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/the-column-column-2-cannot-be-processed-because-more-than-one-code-page-65001-and-1252-are-specified-for-it

Comment: @DaleBurrell Thanks that works.( After selecting code page option when importing the file.)

Answer (score 6):

In the wizard screen for specifying the import file (.csv) you can give the explicit code page as 1252 instead of 65001, that worked for me.

[image: Wizard Screen for specifying the code page]